# Android axml gallery and slidingdrawer in one view

Tags: android, xamarin, gallery, slidingdrawer

I want to have a gallery with images and then i want a little icon at the top as a sliding drawer. But somehow it breaks when i try to fetch the view in my acitivity code.

This line breaks:

```
 SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Coverflow);
```

And here is my axml file:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<Gallery
    android:id="@+id/gallery"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:spacing="20dp" />
<FrameLayout>
    <SlidingDrawer
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/drawer"
        android:handle="@+id/handle"
        android:content="@+id/hej">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/handle"
            android:src="@drawable/bluebutton" />
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:id="@+id/hej">
            <Button
                android:text="Button"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/button4" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </SlidingDrawer>
</FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Is there something wrong with the axml? Or why does it break?

Comment: Non-related: `Gallery` is deprecated as well as `SlidingDrawer`. I wouldn't recommend using them at all, as these can "break" later on if Google decides to remove them completely.
Other than that, do you have a stacktrace? And what's the name of your axml file?

Comment: What do you recommend to use instead? The name of my axml file is Coverflow.axml
The stacktrace is just:

> 0xF in TaskyAndroid.Screens.Coverflow.OnCreate at 

Since it just is about to start the first view

Comment: Usually you would still get a stacktrace - could it be a `NullPointerException`? At what line does it crash?
Instead of `Gallery` I would use a `HorizontalScrollView` and a `SlidingDrawer` could be replaced by something like this: https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel